# Unable to deduce an argument related to Von Mangoldt function

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Consider the algebraic  definition  of Von Mangoldt function as follows: $\Lambda(f) = deg P$ if $f= cP^k$ is  a power of a prime P($k\geq 1$) and is 0 otherwise.

$\sum_{P prime} deg(P) \sum_{m=1} u^{m deg P}  = \sum_{f Monic} \Lambda(f) u^{deg f}$.

As , deg(P) = $\Lambda(f) $ so I can see easily how it is used in deg(P) =$\Lambda(f) $, but I am unable to see how $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} u^{m deg P} = u^{deg f}$ .

Can you please help.

Comment: The von Mangoldt function is defined as $\Lambda(n)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 \log (p) & n=p^k \\
 0 & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array}
\right.
,\ (n\land k)\in\mathbb{N}\land p\in\mathbb{P}$ and satisfies $\log(n)=\sum\limits_{d|n}\Lambda(d)$ and $\Lambda (n)=-\sum\limits_{d|n}\mu(d)\ \log(d)$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mangoldt_function). I'm having trouble relating your question to this definition.

Comment: @Steven Hi!!  Consider looking at page 4 of these notes. http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~rudnick/courses/sieves2015/PPT.pdf . I hope they will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I think the link will help me to understand your question. One thing that initially confused me was deg(P) vs deg P, but it now seems to me the two are meant to be equivalent.

Comment: @StevenClark Can you please tell if you have any ideas for this now?

Comment: Using that on RHS $\Lambda(f)=0$ unless $f=P^m$ for a (monic) prime $P$ one gets that both sides are the double sum $\sum_{P,m \ge 1}u^{m\deg P}$ where $P$ runs through monic prime polynomials of arbitrary degree

Comment: @Conrad Thanks!